# NetBeans project builds fine locally, fails on Travis-ci

Tags: netbeans, ant, travis-ci

All,

I have an open source java8 project, developed with NetBeans (so it's basically ANT, I assume). It builds fine both in the command line (using `ant test`) and in the IDE. The build fails on Travis-ci, claiming that a method is missing:

```
[javac] Compiling 116 source files to /home/travis/build/IQSS/DataTaggingLibrary/DataTagsLib/build/classes
[javac] /home/travis/build/IQSS/DataTaggingLibrary/DataTagsLib/src/edu/harvard/iq/datatags/parser/tagspace/TagSpaceParseResult.java:58: error: no suitable method found for collect(Collector<AbstractSlot,CAP#1,Map<String,List<AbstractSlot>>>)
[javac]         Map<String, List<AbstractSlot>> slotMap = slots.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractSlot::getName));
[javac]                                                                 ^
[javac]     method Stream.<R#1>collect(Supplier<R#1>,BiConsumer<R#1,? super CAP#2>,BiConsumer<R#1,R#1>) is not applicable
[javac]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) R#1
[javac]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
[javac]     method Stream.<R#2,A>collect(Collector<? super CAP#2,A,R#2>) is not applicable
[javac]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) R#2,A,CAP#3,T#2,K
[javac]         (argument mismatch; Collector<CAP#2,CAP#4,Map<String,List<CAP#2>>> cannot be converted to Collector<? super CAP#2,CAP#4,Map<String,List<CAP#2>>>))
[javac]   where R#1,T#1,R#2,A,T#2,K are type-variables:
[javac]     R#1 extends Object declared in method <R#1>collect(Supplier<R#1>,BiConsumer<R#1,? super T#1>,BiConsumer<R#1,R#1>)
[javac]     T#1 extends Object declared in interface Stream
[javac]     R#2 extends Object declared in method <R#2,A>collect(Collector<? super T#1,A,R#2>)
[javac]     A extends Object declared in method <R#2,A>collect(Collector<? super T#1,A,R#2>)
[javac]     T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2,K>groupingBy(Function<? super T#2,? extends K>)
[javac]     K extends Object declared in method <T#2,K>groupingBy(Function<? super T#2,? extends K>)
[javac]   where CAP#1,CAP#2,CAP#3,CAP#4 are fresh type-variables:
[javac]     CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
[javac]     CAP#2 extends AbstractSlot from capture of ? extends AbstractSlot
[javac]     CAP#3 extends Object from capture of ?
[javac]     CAP#4 extends Object from capture of ?
```

Here's the .travis.yml:

```
sudo: false
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
before_script: cd DataTagsLib
script: ant jar test
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Meanwhile, I've changes the code to use another method and get the same effect.
Main mystery unsolved, though :-/